# Computing for Fibonacci becomes slower after adding Memoization Javascript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, performance, recursion, memoization

Comparing the two versions, it seems that the one using memoization is slower when it should be faster in theory. Why is this the case?

---

Without Memoization:

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
}
const start = Date.now();
fibonacci(22);
const duration = Date.now() - start;
console.log(duration);
```

### Output: `11`

---

With Memoization:

```js
function fibonacci(n, dic = {}) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (dic[n]) {
        return dic[n];
    }
    let res = fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    dic[n] = res
    return res
}

const start = Date.now();
fibonacci(22);
console.log(Date.now() - start);
```

### Output: `19`

Comment: I would expect that for small numbers. Try running it with much higher numbers and you should see a difference. If not, then something is wrong with the implementation.

Comment: Also, try using the [Performance interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) for more accurate measurement

Comment: You need to pass in the dictionary to your recursive calls - `let res = fibonacci(n - 1, dic) + fibonacci(n - 2, dic)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your memoized version, you're forgetting to pass `dic` down the recursive call stack. So it gets the default every time.

When you pass it, the time drops to zero on my machine (That way of measuring performance is not particularly accurate - clearly its not zero!)

```js
function fibonacci(n, dic = {}) {
    if (n <= 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (dic[n]) {
        return dic[n];
    }
    let res = fibonacci(n - 1,dic) + fibonacci(n - 2,dic);
    dic[n] = res
    return res
}

const start = Date.now();
fibonacci(22);
console.log(Date.now() - start);
```